# importing xml data from a file on my system to a sql db created in microsoft visual studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, xml, visual-studio

I have created a customer database in Microsoft Visual Studio with one table called customer details. On my system I have an xml file which I created with data that I would like to import into the particular table in the database. However I am having trouble do so since there is no import feature in Microsoft Visual Studio like there is in Access. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you want to import the xml data directly into the DB?

Comment: Yes I would like to import the data directly into my db

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I tried that worked below. Will use the link since code seems to be more efficient.

```
DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
reportData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("newdata.xml"));


SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
   @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Customer.mdf;
   Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
);

SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
sbc.DestinationTableName = "CustomerDetails";

connection.Open();
sbc.WriteToServer(reportData.Tables[0]);
```